# Proclaim, declaim, declare

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Can you please explain the differences between the three symbols `proclaim`, `declaim` and `declare`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

They are [*symbols*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_symbol.htm), not [*keywords*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_kwd.htm).

1. [`proclaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_procla.htm) names a [*function*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababc.htm) for making *global* [declarations](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_c.htm). You should use [`declaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_declai.htm) instead whenever possible.
2. [`declaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_declai.htm) names a [*macro*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababb.htm) for making *global* [declarations](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_c.htm) (like [`proclaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_procla.htm)) which are also effective at *compile-time*.
3. [`declare`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_declar.htm) is just a [*symbol*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_symbol.htm) (i.e., it does not name a [function](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababc.htm), [macro](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababb.htm), or [special operator](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababa.htm)) for making *local* [declarations](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_c.htm) in the beginning of *some* forms (you can view it as an element of *syntax* of those forms).

So, the first two affect the [global environment](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_g.htm#global_environment) and the last one is [local](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_l.htm#local_declaration).

[`declaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_declai.htm) is preferable over [`proclaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_procla.htm) because it has an immediate effect in the [compilation environment](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_c.htm#compilation_environment):

> Although the execution of a [`proclaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_procla.htm) form has effects that might
>   affect compilation, the compiler does not make any attempt to
>   recognize and specially process proclaim forms. A proclamation such as
>   the following, even if a top level form, does not have any effect
>   until it is executed:
>
> `(proclaim '(special *x*))`
>
> If compile time side effects are desired,
>   [`eval-when`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_eval_w.htm) may be useful. For example:
>
> `(eval-when (:execute :compile-toplevel :load-toplevel)
>    (proclaim '(special *x*)))`
>
> In most such cases, however, it is preferrable to use
>   [`declaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_declai.htm) for this purpose.

I.e., if your code is

```
(proclaim '(special *x*))
(defun foo () (print *x*))
```

the compiler will complain that `foo` reads an unknown special variable `*x*`,  while

```
(declaim (special *x*))
(defun foo () (print *x*))
```

will cause no warnings.

**PS**. If you are wondering why CL even has [`proclaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_procla.htm): first, historically it was there before [`declaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_declai.htm), and, second, [`proclaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_procla.htm) is simpler and more useful in macros.

Comment: Thank you sds!  Could you clarify the difference between `proclaim` and `declaim`?  I have changed the word "keyword" in my question, it was confusing. I was trying to explicitely hide the kind of symbol, but the word symbol was just as fine.

Comment: The difference between them is just that: one is a function and, ordinarily, has no effect at compilation time, while the other is a macro which affects the compilation environment. You really need to read the spec for details.

Comment: Alright, I get it now, thanks.  Honestly the [Hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_procla.htm) is a bit hard to understand, but I will try to refer to it in the future.

Comment: The spec is the reference; it is best to start with a textbook, like Graham's ANSI CL or Seibel's Practical CL.

Comment: sds: you have written some great answers to other questions in the past, and while your summary of the nature of proclaim, declaim and declare are very true, the rest of the answer boils down to read a book or read the hyperspec. I was pretty excited to see the answer to this question as, while I use declaim, I don't have a good intuition of its behaviour and I find the hyperspec's info on the subject is a little dense. Any chance you could expand this answer to include the behaviour of the functions & macros in question? Thanks

Comment: @Baggers, thanks this is exactly the reason why I asked this question, and thanks to sds for enriching it.