# Extracting a regex match in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, cl-ppcre

I must be missing something very basic here.

I need to extract a capture group from a match in common lisp. 
When I eval in the interpreter (an sbcl implementation):

```
`(cl-ppcre::scan-to-strings ".*?(\\d).png" "sample1.png")`
```

I get:

```
"sample1.png"
#("1")
```

But if I bind that expression to a value, say

```
`(setq number (cl-ppcre::scan-to-strings ".*(\\d).png" "sample1.png"))`
```

The value of number is becomes `"sample1.png"`. How do I get the `"1"`, which is printed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [values function in Common Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795608/values-function-in-common-lisp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Your question

You are looking for

```
(setf (values match position) 
      (cl-ppcre::scan-to-strings ".*(\\d).png" "sample1.png"))
```

See also [`multiple-value-bind`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_multip.htm#multiple-value-bind) et al.

## Under the hood

Common lisp functions can return [multiple values](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_abc.htm).
This corresponds to "tuple" return value in other languages, such as Python.
So, when a lisp function, such as [`floor`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_floorc.htm), return multiple values, a Python user will write something like

```
(f,r) = floor(10,3)
```

and `floor` will (usually) allocate a tuple, which is captured when you write `fr = floor(10,3)`.

CL multiple values do not allocate extra storage, but the extra values are discarded unless you specifically ask for them:

```
(setf (values f r) (floor 10 3))
```

will capture both values, but `(setf f (floor 10 3))` will discard `r`.

Comment: Shortly after I asked this I somewhat figured how to extract what I wanted, but without really understanding what was going on. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Is it possible to bind multiple values within a let form?

Comment: `multiple-value-bind` might be what you are looking for

Comment: Actually, I mean binding multiple values within the VARLIST section of a let. The only way I can think of doing this is through a macro.

Comment: Try [`multiple-value-list`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_mult_1.htm)