# how to write a common lisp function that returns multiple values

Tags: common-lisp

I'm doing a tut on lisp http://common-lisp.net/language.html#sec-1
and am wondering how would this function be written:

```
(my-floor 1.3) 
 => 1 0.3
```

Comment: The link you reference tells you ... You just use values.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Return_multiple_values#Common_Lisp

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered just several paragraphs down in the document linked in the question.

Comment: I'm a little bit surprised at the downvotes here. its always easy when you have the answer and know where to look. Yes I know its an obvious question but sometimes its the obvious ones that need to be addressed first before any learning can be done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`values`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/a_values.htm):

```
(defun foo (x y)
  (values x y (+ x y) (cons x y)))
```

Try the function:

```
> (foo 2 pi)
2 ;
3.1415926535897932385L0 ;
5.1415926535897932383L0 ;
(2 . 3.1415926535897932385L0)
```

Use the returned values with [`multiple-value-bind`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_multip.htm):

```
(multiple-value-bind (a b sum pair) (foo 1 2)
  (list a b sum pair))
==> (1 2 3 (1 . 2))
```

or `(setf values)`.

See also [values function in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22795608/850781).

Comment: How does one access these values in code? Is that a list of values?

Comment: Much appreciated!