# CLISP: Returning stdout, stderr, and retcode from a shell command

Tags: shell, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am using Common Lisp for some scripting and wanted to have [`run-program`](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/shell.html) execute shell commands. I have been trying to manipulate the output to get a list in the form `(output error returncode)` but I can only get either the output or the returncode from **run-program**.

The arguments here only give you `:output` (there is no `:error`):

Is there a way of getting all three? Something like this:

```
(setf retcode (my-special-cmd "ls" :output stream1 :error stream2))
(print (list stream1 stream2 retcode))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [values function in Common Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795608/values-function-in-common-lisp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`run-program`](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/shell.html) returns [multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22795608/850781).
You can handle them as explained in the linked question.

The doc you link to says:

> If :STREAM was specified for :INPUT or :OUTPUT, a Lisp STREAM is returned. If :STREAM was specified for both :INPUT and :OUTPUT, three Lisp STREAMs are returned, as for the function EXT:MAKE-PIPE-IO-STREAM.

Thus what you need is either

```
(EXT:MAKE-PIPE-IO-STREAM "ls")
```

or

```
(ext:run-program "ls" :input :stream :output :stream)
```

Then you will have to read from the streams returned to get the command output. However, in this case you will lose the exit code.