# how to split a list recursively with using conditions in clisp

Tags: list, recursion, common-lisp

I am trying to learn clisp and I have started learning how to manipulate lists recursively. I am unsure wether it is my logic or if I am just too unfamiliar with the constructs of lisp, for some I am able to do it i.e. for procedure `(separate '(a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4)) => ((1 2 3 4) (a b c d))` by doing

```
(defun separate (lst)
  (if (endp lst)
      '(nil nil)
      (let ((x (separate (cdr lst))))
         (if (numberp (car lst))
             (list (cons (car lst)
                         (car x)))
             (list (car x)
                   (cons (car lst) (cadr x)))))))
```

but when I do the same approach for another procedure

`(greater-than-n '(9 1 8 2 7 3 6 4) 5)`

I would expect to get a list : `((9 8 7 6) (1 2 3 4))`

but instead I get: `((9 8 7 6))`

My program thus far is:

```
(defun greater-than-n (lst n)
    (if (endp lst)
        '(() ())
        (let ((x (greater-than-n (cdr lst) n)))
             (if (> (car lst) n) 
                 (list (cons (car lst)      
                             (car x)))
                 (list (car x)
                       (cons (car lst) 
                             (car x)))))))
```

I appreciate any help or comments.

Comment: what is `part` function? did you mean `greater-than-n`?

Comment: yes, sorry, I have corrected it, along with other various mistakes in my question

Comment: can you please confirm `(separate '(a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4)) => ((1 2 3 4) (a b c d))` ? i'm on sbcl now, not clisp, but it's also common-lisp, and i get `((1 2 3 4) (A 1 2 3 4))`

Comment: sorry, I typed (car x) instead of (cadr x) for the last cell

Comment: thanks for updating question, but now i get `((1 2 3 4) (A))`, still not `((1 2 3 4) (A B C D))`

Comment: I have updated the code for separate again, as far as I can tell they are identical but it works on gnu-clisp interpreter, perhaps it has a different implementation than sbcl?

Comment: i'm pretty sure your `separate` function still didn't work (as pointed also in the answer provided by @sds). but it's great you figure out how to fix it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bug is in the

```
             (list (cons (car lst)      
                         (car x)))
```

form: you are returning a list of 1 element.

PS. Your functions seem like a textbook case for using [multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22796346/850781) instead of a list of values.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the bug, I have corrected it to
`(list (cons (car lst)
                  (car x))
        (cadr x))`

Comment: I would reserve multiple values for ancillary values. Perhaps a touch of destructuring-bind?

Comment: @RomscaZ. In addition you use `(car x)` as the tail of both answers. The second list is never used.