# prog vs. let in LISP performance difference

Tags: scope, lisp, let

I have been told that in lisp, `let` is faster than `prog` (but `prog` has a bit more of flexibility), when making variables scoped. My question is: Why? I mean, there are certain times when using `prog` is easier, however, except for empirical tests, I don't know how to guess the effect. Is it when allocating memory? Is it execution? Does it come more when looping? I don't know the implementation differences' specifics.

Comment: Which version of Scheme are you referring to? Neither R5RS nor R6RS contain any prog.

Comment: It is Cadnce SKILL++

Comment: Cadence SKILL++ seems to be descended from Franz Lisp (which itself is kind of cool, that something is still using it all these years later).  It's possible that Franz Lisp had performance differences between `let` and `prog` although I can't find any mention of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Lisp

The description of [`prog`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_prog_.htm) says:

> `prog` can be explained in terms of [`block`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_block.htm), [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm), and [`tagbody`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_tagbod.htm) as follows:

```
(prog variable-list declaration . body)
==  (block nil (let variable-list declaration (tagbody . body)))
```

In other words, functionally speaking, `prog` is a strict superset of
`let` (except for a small vignette: the former returns `nil` while the latter returns the [value(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22795608/850781) of its last form).

A proverbial ["sufficiently smart
compiler"](http://wiki.c2.com/?SufficientlySmartCompiler) - in fact,
*any* modern Lisp compiler - can detect that
[`return`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_return.htm) and
[`go`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_go.htm) are not used and compile the
`prog` identically to the equivalent `let`:

```
(disassemble '(lambda () (let ((a 1) (b 2)) (print (+ a b)) nil)))
```

and

```
(disassemble '(lambda () (prog ((a 1) (b 2)) (print (+ a b)))))
```

produce identical output:

```
Disassembly of function :LAMBDA
(CONST 0) = 1
(CONST 1) = 2
0 required arguments
0 optional arguments
No rest parameter
No keyword parameters
7 byte-code instructions:
0     (CONST&PUSH 0)                      ; 1
1     (CONST&PUSH 1)                      ; 2
2     (CALLSR&PUSH 2 55)                  ; +
5     (PUSH-UNBOUND 1)
7     (CALLS1 142)                        ; PRINT
9     (NIL)
10    (SKIP&RET 1)
NIL
```

## [Cadence SKILL++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence_SKILL)

You might want to ask the implementors.