# Function outputs a list but returns nil

Tags: return, output, lisp, common-lisp, variable-assignment

I call a function, which outputs a list, I want to use afterwards. I try to bind the function's output to a variable, but instead of the list it gets assigned `NIL`.

My call and output (observe the newline in the output):

```
(nqthm-eval `(myghs 1 NIL ,g1)) ==> '(T (B . E) (D . D))
```

When I try to bind this output to a variable `v` it gets assigned `NIL`:

```
(setq v (nqthm-eval `(myghs 1 NIL ,g1))) ==> '(T (B . E) (D . D))
NIL
```

And an equality check afterwards indeed gives:

```
(equal v NIL) ==> T
```

It seems to me, that the function call to `nqthm-eval` is *outputting* the list and *returning* `NIL`, although I don't understand LISP enough for this yet.

**My question:** Is there a way to get the list part of the output/return of my function like `(car (nqthm-eval ...))` or `(get_output (nqthm-eval ...))` from the 'outside'?

Comment: I also tried `(setf (values v rest) (nqthm-eval ...))` but then both variables `v` and `rest` are assigned `NIL`.

Comment: probably the software you are using has an option to do so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between a function's *return value* and its *output*.

The return value is just the [value (or values)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22795608/850781) of the last form and is captured by [`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm) et al.

The output is sent to a stream and can only be captured from it.

E.g.,

```lisp
(defun foo1 (x)
  (princ (1+ x))
  (1- x))
(foo1 12)
```

will print `13` and return `11`.

If you want to capture both, you need

```lisp
(defun foo2 (x)
  (values (1+ x) (1- x)))
(setf (values a b) (foo2 17))
```

and now `a` is `18` and `b` is `16`.

**PS**. Actually, if you do not have control over the function source code and still want to capture its output, you can do it *if* you know *where* it sends its output. E.g.:

```lisp
(setq b (with-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
          (setq a (foo1 1))))
```

now `b` is `"2"` (a `string`!) while `a` is `0` (a `number`!)

Comment: Too bad this function sends it to a stream :/ But thank you anyway for your nice explanation!