# Can someone help to me with common-lisp Code?

Tags: common-lisp

What happens in the following common-lisp Code with number 2 and 3:

```
"(values (values 1 2 3) 4 5)"
```

Output is: 1 4 5.

Someone in another forum explain to me, that "the values 2 and 3 are effectively discarded because the outer "(values ...)" call, only cares about first value of the inner "(values 1 2 3)" call.

My question is, why does this happen?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795608/values-function-in-common-lisp

Comment: Also see [values](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_values.htm) in the HyperSpec.

Answer (score 2):

`values` is a function: in particular it is not a special operator.  For a function named *f* in CL then `(`*f* *v1* *v2* ...`)`:

- evaluates each of the *v1*, *v2*, ... in order, collecting a single value from each one, either the first value, or if there are no values then `nil`;
- calls *f* with these values.

This explains why `(values (values ...))` selects only the first value from the inner `values` call.

If you want to collect all the values you need a special form where the normal function-call semantics are not followed.  CL provides a special operator which lets you write such forms: [`multiple-value-call`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_multip.htm), and the trick is that the function argument in the special form should be `values` itself:

```
> (multiple-value-call #'values (values 1 2 3) 4 5)
1
2
3
4
5
*
```